# Excel: Remove Multiple Rows if COLUMN equals VALUE

Tags: excel, rows

Is there a macro somebody knows of or could write that would check all the rows of a document and remove all rows that have at least one of these conditions:

- **Column  F** = 0
- **Column  N** = 0
- **Column AT** = FALSE
- **Column AU** = FALSE
- **Column AV** = *Sold*
- **Column  Z** = *staged*

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub RemoveRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim r As Long
    For r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row Step -1
        If Cells(r, 6) = 0 Or Cells(r, 14) = 0 _
            Or Cells(r, 46) = False Or Cells(r, 47) = False _
                Or Cells(r, 48) = "Sold" Or Cells(r, 26) = "staged" _
                    Then Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. Debugger said it was this row: For r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows - 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row Step -1

Comment: Edited... it should be usedrange.rows.count -1.

Comment: Note that this will delete rows that have blanks in columns F, N, AT, or AU because (blank) equals 0 and it equals FALSE.

Comment: The only columns that could have a blank in it are AV and Z.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a table (and not really need the macro).  Select all of your data, go to the insert menu, and click table (on the left hand side).  Use the dropdowns at the top of the columns to select your data filters.

Comment: In Excel? There is no 'Table' in Insert? Isn't Excel already a table? :P

Comment: @Devin Which version do you have?  Technically it is all a table, but this exposes some features like the ones you are after.

Comment: Ah. 2003.

I found Table in the Data menu, but I don't know what cells to select for this.

Comment: @Devin I would select everything, as it will then automatically remove the entire row of data (not just the specific columns) for you